# Which graphics am I using?

Tags: 18.04, lts

```
suman@suman-VPCCB15FG:~$ lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Whistler [Radeon HD 6630M/6650M/6750M/7670M/7690M] (rev ff)
```

Comment: Either of those ;-) from lspci we can only determine you have a built-in Intel and a Radeon graphics card. What you are using .... see the menu option "additional drivers"

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Gnome Shell, type "about" in the overview and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. The graphics card you are using is shown in the window. As you can see in the attached screenshot, I am using the Nvidia card.

[image]